# Formatting values with javascript

Tags: javascript

in a previous question was having doubts with the removal of all the points and commas of my array but for accounting of these values this is bad how can I replace the commas of my cents in points?

```
var arr = ['1,00',
'10,00',
'500,00',
'5.000,00',
'70.000,00',
'900.000,00',
'1.000.000,00']

arr.map(value => alert(Number(value.split(',')[0].replace(/[^0-9]+/g,""))))
```

https://jsfiddle.net/smachs/fdchzupm

Example of the result that I hope:

```
1,98 => 1.98
10,50 => 10.53
500,47 => 500.47
5.000,64 => 5000.64
70.000,29 => 70000.29
900.000,16 => 900000.16
1.000.000,07 => 1000000.07
```

Thanks for help me xD

Comment: Why would you use `alert` in the `map` function?

Comment: @Xufox are only test I will revert this logic to json formatting

Comment: Hint: use `console.log()` instead of alert()

Comment: @Xufox yes but jsfiddle only displays with `alert` or `document.write`

Comment: @smachs Have you opened the developer tools to see the console logs?

Comment: @Xufox did not know, it was a bit strange I was expecting a external console similiar to codepen, thanks a lot for the tip :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it:

```js
var arr = ['1,00',
'10,00',
'500,00',
'5.000,00',
'70.000,00',
'900.000,00',
'1.000.000,00']

arr = arr.map(v => v.replace(/\./g, "").replace(",", "."));
console.log(arr);
```

The important part is `.replace(/\./g, "").replace(",", ".")` what this does is to first remove all `.` characters from the string and then replace the `,` character with `.`.

Comment: Also should point out needs to be string not Number to display `.00` as decimal